# Jax fitting MLP gives different result than Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jax, mlp

I need to build a MLP in Jax, but I get slightly different (and in my opinion inaccurate) result from Jax respect to a MLP created in Tensorflow.

In both cases I created a dataset where the y are linear function of X plus a standard gaussian error, the dataset is the same in both cases.

I initialized the MLP in tensorflow with the same initialization I did in Jax (to be sure to start with the exact same network).

In Tensorflow I fit the network using this:

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = 0.00001))
model.fit(X, y, batch_size = X.shape[0], epochs = 5000)
```

And this is what I get (it seems correct):

[image: Tensorflow Result]

Now, in Jax i train the network as follows:

```
loss = lambda params, x, y: jnp.mean((apply_fn(params, x) - y) ** 2)
@jit
def update(params, x, y, learning_rate):
    grad_loss = grad(loss)(params, x, y)
    # SGD update
    return jax.tree_util.tree_map(
        lambda p, g: p - learning_rate * g, params, grad_loss  # for every leaf i.e. for every param of MLP
    )

learning_rate = 0.00001
num_epochs = 5000
for _ in range(num_epochs):
    params = update(params, X, y, learning_rate)
```

This is what I get as result:

[image: Jax Result]

I notice that if I increase a lot the number of epochs in the Jax implementation it works better (the model predictions get closer and closer to the real values) but how can I get a similar result from Jax to Tensorflow without increasing the number of epochs?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure what's going on without code to reproduce the issue, but I suspect this comes from JAX doing the optimization in float32 precision, while TF is doing the optimization in float64 precision. See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#double-64bit-precision. If that's not the issue, then you may have better luck getting a helpful answer if you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The problem is that it's kind hard to provide a minimal reproducible example because I need to give you 2 examples, one for TF and one for Jax. Anyway, the update procedure I implemented in Jax is correct, right? I mean, tensorflow doesn't do anything more than that, right? Because I saw that the SGD class in keras has many parameters, I left them at their default values ​​hoping they didn't do some kind of optimization (which explains why with the same number of iterations in Tensorflow you get a better fit)

Comment: I honestly don’t know. Did you try 64-bit precision in JAX?

Comment: It took me a while because I'm not using pure Jax, but a library built on top of Jax, so I had to implement the MLP in pure Jax to be able to initialize the weights with vectors in float64, nothing has changed compared to float32, so that's not the problem.

Comment: My comment was not about changing the input values, it was about enabling float64 computation globally. See the link I shared in my first comment. If you don't do that, then even float64 inputs will lead to float32 computations. That idea is really a stab in the dark and may or may not work: it's hard to guess much of anything about code that I can't see or run :)

Comment: I saw the link you shared, I enabled float64 computation and to be sure that all is working fine I implemented the MLP in pure Jax. Nothing changed.

Comment: Ok, well best of luck then. If you’re able to share complete code, I think you’d be likely to get better answers.

Comment: If you want to look at the code you can find it in this [repository](https://github.com/FabianoVeglianti/temporaryCodeRepository)

Comment: Before running any SGD step, your TF loss function returns `3512` and your JAX loss funciton returns `3599`. This suggests that the two models are not equivalent. I would start by looking at how the models are defined and figuring out how they're different.

Comment: Good point, thank you a lot! I will investigate in that direction!